# Getting a Memory allocation error in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

I'm using Dymola 2019 and have to use +50 instances of CombiTimeTable in my model to load a CSV file with a size greater than 200 MB (Yearly Weather data with a resolution of 60 s).

An additional increase of my model resulted in getting the following error message in Dymola:

```
Error: The following error was detected at time: 0
Memory allocation error
FixInitials:Init: Integrator failed to start model.
```

A dirty fix to this problem is possible if I split up the big csv file into smaller shunks, but this is obviously not the best solution to my problem.

How can I increase the designated Memory for Dymola or what is a best practice loading big csv files. Is another format more efficent?

Comment: You could try to import the data using the sdf data format. The free library comes with your dymola installment. Open the library under File-->Libraries-->SDF.
You can use the SDFEditor or python to create the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `Advanced.CompileWith64=2` inside Dymola should generate a 64-bit dymosim-executable that avoids this issue.

Specifically the message "Memory allocation error" only occurs if you are out of dynamic memory for malloc.